# On VSTS How do I configure a branch pattern for CI?

Tags: azure-pipelines

When trying to set up a trigger for my features branches (features/*) I take note of the following tooltip when trying to create a brnch trigger in VSTS...

> There must be at least one filter for the trigger to be valid.
>   Patterns are supported.
>
> For example, master will build that branch on check-in. features/*
>   will build any branch under features/ on check-in.

However I can only seem to select a branch from a drop down list and filter that list.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question but pattern matching for build and release definitions does work, you first have to create the definition against a static branch e.g. 'master' and then update the build definition trigger. (I found it super counter-intuitive too!).

[image]

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/7123) may also be of interest as a potential future enhancement to selecting the default branch for scheduled and manual builds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you missed anything.

VSTS builds connect with the repository branches in two ways:

1. Default Branch from Repository tab. When you Queue a new build the default branch is selected by Default
2. Continous Integration Triggers from Triggers tab
   [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a67Y.png).

Trigger means when any change is detected in the defined branch build the changed branch and may be create Artifacts if defined in the branch.[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIVOg.png)

Hope it helps.